# Elixir is not defined error

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am using laravel 5.4 and I wanted to set up elixir to compile sass files.  I tried to install elixir by running `$ npm install` and after that, I tried running `$ gulp` but it gave me the following error:

```
/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/gulpfile.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { elixir(mix => {
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: elixir is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/gulpfile.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at execute (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:24:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:149:63)
```

After adding `const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');`, I am getting this error:

```
[02:28:30] Starting 'webpack'...
{ [Error: ./resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue
Module parse failed: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div class="row">
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 16:25-60]
  message: './resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue\nModule parse failed: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue Unexpected token (1:0)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.\n| <template>\n|     <div class="container">\n|         <div class="row">\n @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 16:25-60',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'webpack-stream',
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
```

Comment: you might need to add elixir to your import list as:
`const { elixir } = require('laravel-elixir');`

Comment: In which file? @PaladiN

Comment: If you are calling from `Webpack.mix.js` use the above import, and if you are using  `gulpfile.js` (as i see you are using) use `const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');`

Comment: @PaladiN after adding that line I'm getting the above line...is this a different issue?

Comment: The error is due to the `laravel-elixir` doesn't know about `.vue` component. You need to add https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2 to compile the `.vue` components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue when installing a new laravel app 5.4. When I try to run `gulp webpack` it shows same error in my console. So what I did, since the laravel 5.4 comes with the new vue version which is the `vue 2`. You need to require `require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');` See sample below:

gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2'); // recommended for vue 2
elixir(function(mix) {
    // some mixes here..
    mix.webpack('app.js');
});
```

> If you got errors like elixir related, just npm install them. also check this page [here](https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2)
>   .